# Detecting and deleting "" of a returned split function array

Tags: javascript

I want to convert string into array using split when i have this string
which i want to convert it to array. Here is my code :

```
var str = "Hello  I am     Here";
var separator = str.split(" ");
console.log(separator); // returns ['Hello', '', 'I', 'am', '', '', '', '', 'Here']
for(var i in separator){
    if(separator[i] == ""){
        separator.splice(i,1);
    }
}
console.log(separator); // returns ['Hello', 'I', 'am', '', '', 'Here']
```

but when i'm using split and deleting some null strings some of them arent deleted. why?

Comment: no. my problem is the empty string array indices arent deleted

Comment: the short version is that you're changing the array (with splice) while looping

Comment: separator.filter(x => x !== "") should do the trick. @user19513069 is right though, don't modify array while you are looping it.

Comment: I think instead of your for-loop, I would use a an array filter and filter out the empty strings.